# MYSQL Union Query Order by second inner query

Tags: mysql, union

I need to pull categories from a table so I use a union query to add the first row "All Categories" and then in the second query I am trying to sort by Category Name, but it is not sorting the 2nd query. I can't seem to figure it out, please help:

```
(SELECT 99, 'All Categories' as t1)  
union
(SELECT ID, CatName FROM prodcattypes as t2 WHERE VendorTypeID = 2 order by t2.CatName)
```

Comment: What is the issue? The query [seems to work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d27d4/1).

Comment: Hi sorry!  It is not sorting the 2nd query

Comment: I edited the question now to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the records after a `UNION` is undefined if you don't have an exterior `ORDER BY` clause. You have a few options, here's a simple one:

```
SELECT ID, CatName FROM (
    (SELECT 99 AS ID, 'All Categories' AS CatName, 1 AS TableOrder)  
    UNION
    (
        SELECT ID, CatName, 2 AS TableOrder
        FROM prodcattypes as t2
        WHERE VendorTypeID = 2
        ORDER BY t2.CatName
    )
) OrderedCategories
ORDER BY TableOrder ASC, CatName ASC
```

The idea is to assign a fixed "rank" to records from both parts of the `UNION` and use it to order the results.